# An object at the specified path C:\Users\user~1.name does not exist

Tags: powershell, tfs, vnext

So today I came across an issue whereby a powershell script was causing the deployment to fail. This job is set-up exactly the same on other machines. This one however just refused to work.
The error was:

> An object at the specified path C:\Users\user~1.name does not exist

heres the full log at the time of failure

```
2017-01-11T15:03:12.1295730Z Executing the powershell script: D:\Tfs\Agent2\tasks\PowerShellOnTargetMachines\1.0.25\PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3014605Z ##[debug]Entering script PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3014605Z ##[debug]environmentName = ***

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3014605Z ##[debug]adminUserName = ***\**.**

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3170816Z ##[debug]protocol = Http

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3170816Z ##[debug]testCertificate = true

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3170816Z ##[debug]resourceFilteringMethod = machineNames

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3170816Z ##[debug]machineNames = 

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3170816Z ##[debug]scriptPath = c:\temp\release\ReleaseScripts\ReplaceVariables.ps1

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3170816Z ##[debug]scriptArguments = -FilePath E:\***\web.config

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3170816Z ##[debug]initializationScriptPath = 

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3170816Z ##[debug]runPowershellInParallel = true

2017-01-11T15:03:12.3327091Z ##[debug]sessionVariables = $__ManualImportDropLocation__=wewqewq,$enableDetailedLogging=true

2017-01-11T15:03:12.4420874Z ##[debug]Starting Register-Environment cmdlet call for environment : *** with filter 

2017-01-11T15:03:12.4577127Z ##[debug]Completed Register-Environment cmdlet call for environment : ***

2017-01-11T15:03:12.4577127Z ##[debug]Starting Get-EnvironmentResources cmdlet call on environment name: ***

2017-01-11T15:03:12.4733388Z ##[debug]Starting Get-EnvironmentProperty cmdlet call on environment name: *** with key: Microsoft-Vslabs-MG-SkipCACheck

2017-01-11T15:03:12.4733388Z ##[debug]Completed Get-EnvironmentProperty cmdlet call on environment name: *** with key: Microsoft-Vslabs-MG-SkipCACheck

2017-01-11T15:03:12.4889674Z ##[debug]Get Resource properties for *** (ResourceId = 1)

2017-01-11T15:03:12.4889674Z ##[debug]Starting Get-EnvironmentProperty cmdlet call on environment name: *** with resource id: 1(Name : ***) and key: Microsoft-Vslabs-MG-Resource-FQDN

2017-01-11T15:03:12.4889674Z ##[debug]Completed Get-EnvironmentProperty cmdlet call on environment name: *** with resource id: 1(Name : ***) and key: Microsoft-Vslabs-MG-Resource-FQDN

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5045997Z ##[debug]Starting Get-Environment cmdlet call on environment name: ***

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5202195Z ##[debug]Completed Get-Environment cmdlet call on environment name: ***

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5227541Z ##[debug]Starting Get-EnvironmentProperty cmdlet call on environment name: *** with resource id: 1(Name : ***) and key: WinRM_Http

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5385567Z ##[debug]Completed Get-EnvironmentProperty cmdlet call on environment name: *** with resource id: 1(Name : ***) and key: WinRM_Http

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5385567Z ##[debug]       Resource Username - ***\***.***

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5541595Z Deployment started for machine: '***:5985'

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5854089Z ##[debug]fqdn = ***

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5854089Z ##[debug]scriptPath = c:\temp\release\ReleaseScripts\***.ps1

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5854089Z ##[debug]port = 5985

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5854089Z ##[debug]scriptArguments = -FilePath E:\***\web.config

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5854089Z ##[debug]initializationScriptPath = 

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5854089Z ##[debug]protocolOption = -UseHttp

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5854089Z ##[debug]skipCACheckOption = 

2017-01-11T15:03:12.5854089Z ##[debug]enableDetailedLogging = false

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6010328Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6010328Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.WindowsForms.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6010328Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6010328Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6010328Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.VsTestLogger.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6010328Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Chat.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DeleteTeamProject.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Diff.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Discussion.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Interfaces.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Logger.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Strings.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Worker.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.TestIntegration.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6166590Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Lab.WorkflowIntegration.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Policy.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SharePointReporting.Integration.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Test.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestImpact.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Common.Integration.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Work.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryLanguage.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6322851Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6479103Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CodeReview.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6479103Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CodeReview.Discussion.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6479103Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.CodeReview.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6479103Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6479103Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6479103Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Newtonsoft.Json.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6479103Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6479103Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DevTestLabs.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6635512Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Client.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6635512Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Common.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6635512Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Definition.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.6791675Z ##[debug]Loading .NET assembly:    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.dll

2017-01-11T15:03:12.7104184Z ##[debug]Initiating deployment on ***

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7003726Z ##[debug]Finished Deployment operation on ***:5985

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7003726Z ##[debug]Deployment logs for Deployment operation on ***:5985 

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z ##[debug]

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z     Deployment started on target machine...

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z System.AggregateException: Failed to create working directory on the machine. Consult the logs below for details of the error.

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z An object at the specified path C:\Users\***~1.*** does not exist. ---> System.Management.Automation.CmdletProviderInvocationException: An object at the specified path C:\Users\***~1.*** does not exist. ---> System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: An object at the specified path C:\Users\***~1.*** does not exist.

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.NormalizeThePath(String basepath, Stack`1 tokenizedPathStack)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.NormalizeRelativePathHelper(String path, String basePath)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<Invoke>b__0()

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute[T](Func`1 action)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable, ActionPreference errorActionPreference)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable, ActionPreference errorActionPreference)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.DeploymentService.SetWorkingDirectory(IPowerShell powerShellSession, String machineName, Int32 powershellPort, String tempMofDirectory)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.DeploymentService.RunPowerShellScripts(DeploymentMachineSpecification deploymentMachine, ScriptSpecification scriptSpecification, ScriptSpecification initializationScriptSpecification, String applicationPath, IPowerShell powerShellSession)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.CmdletProviderInvocationException: An object at the specified path C:\Users\***~1.*** does not exist. ---> System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: An object at the specified path C:\Users\***~1.*** does not exist.

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.NormalizeThePath(String basepath, Stack`1 tokenizedPathStack)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProvider.NormalizeRelativePathHelper(String path, String basePath)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7160894Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke(IEnumerable input, PSInvocationSettings settings)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass28_0.<Invoke>b__0()

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.<Execute>b__0()

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Utilities.RetryExecutor.Execute[T](Func`1 action)

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.RemoteDeployer.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable, ActionPreference errorActionPreference)<---

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z ##[debug]Service logs for Deployment operation on ***:5985 

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z ##[debug]RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 10 : [RemoteDeployer][11:Jan:17:15:3:14:1141; 716, 4](***)Creating public key for communication

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 2 : [RemoteDeployer][11:Jan:17:15:3:14:1141; 716, 4](***)Created public key for communication

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z RemoteDeployerSource Information: 12 : [RemoteDeployer][11:Jan:17:15:3:14:1297; 716, 4](***)Deployment service - VisualStudioRemoteDeployerfd782f8c-20e6-47ca-80b1-a79ed7d375d5 is running...

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 4 : [RemoteDeployer][11:Jan:17:15:3:15:1495; 716, 6](***)Input file found

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 5 : [RemoteDeployer][11:Jan:17:15:3:15:1495; 716, 6](***)Reading input parameters

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7316466Z RemoteDeployerSource Verbose: 6 : [RemoteDeployer][11:Jan:17:15:3:15:1495; 716, 6](***)Finished reading input parameters

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7472527Z Deployment status for machine '***:5985' : 'Failed'

2017-01-11T15:03:16.7785160Z ##[debug]System.Exception: An object at the specified path C:\Users\***~1.*** does not exist.

2017-01-11T15:03:16.8097547Z ##[error]An object at the specified path C:\Users\***~1.*** does not exist. For more info please refer to http://aka.ms/powershellontargetmachinesreadme
```

Comment: You really did not give much information here. What was your deployment tool? What was the job doing? There was nothing to even troubleshoot off of here.

Comment: @ShawnEsterman would you like me to move the link in the answer to the question? I thought the tags would be sufficient enough to describe that the deployment tool is TFS build (vnext)

Comment: @ShawnEsterman updated for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling I came across [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/id-ID/a8ed53a6-1052-4943-8c27-fe1431bd34f5/vnext-build-cannot-deploy-test-agent-with-user-folder-contains-tilde-character?forum=tfsbuild).
The error was pretty much describing the same thing as I was seeing.

However the answer "please use another account" was less than satisfactory to me. Nevertheless I tried a different account and it worked successfully.

I then deleted the c:\users\user.name folder and relogged on with the original account. Usually the Folder c:\users\user.name would be recreated however in this case it created c:\users\temp.

After a quick google again it appears that windows does this when your profile is all out of whack. After removing the profile from the registry and another logon it created the correct folder.

Then finally put the jobs original credentials in and it all worked :)

Comment: Deleting a folder from C:\Users is not the equivalent of removing a user profile from a machine. Use this: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6619/beginner-geek-delete-user-accounts-in-windows-7/

Comment: @ShawnEsterman the linked guide appears to show removing of a user however this user is not local to this machine it is from active directory. The user works on other machines just fine just not this one

Comment: @Cece-MSFT I will do tomorrow as unfortunately you can only answer your own questions two days after asking.

Comment: @ShawnEsterman this guide was much more appropriate http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/shyjumohan/fix-corrupt-user-profile-temp-profile-in-windows-server-20/